# Unable to push data to server using Asynchronous RPC with DCE pipes

Tags: asynchronous, pipe, rpc

I want to push data to the server using Asynchronous RPC with pipes. Here is my code:

```
//file: Xasyncpipe.idl:   
interface IMyAsyncPipe
{
//define the pipe type
typedef pipe int ASYNC_INTPIPE;

int MyAsyncInputPipe(
    handle_t hBinding, 
    [in] ASYNC_INTPIPE *inpipe) ;
};



//file:Xasyncpipe.acf:
interface IMyAsyncPipe
{
[async] MyAsyncInputPipe () ;
} ;



//file:Client.cpp
mian()
{
// Creates a binding handle.
...
RPC_ASYNC_STATE Async;
status = RpcAsyncInitializeHandle(&Async, sizeof(RPC_ASYNC_STATE));
Async.UserInfo = NULL;
Async.NotificationType = RpcNotificationTypeIoc;
Async.u.IOC.hIOPort = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, 0, 0);
ASYNC_INTPIPE inputPipe;

// Calls the RPC function.
MyAsyncInputPipe(&Async, hBinding, &inputPipe);
}



//file:Server.cpp
void MyAsyncInputPipe(PRPC_ASYNC_STATE state, handle_t hBinding, ASYNC_INTPIPE *pipe)
{
std::cout << "Input Test" << std::endl;
}
```

I added a breakpoint in function MyAsyncInputPipe, and the breakpoint is never triggered.

I change the Xasyncpipe.idl from `[in] ASYNC_INTPIPE *inpipe` to `[out] ASYNC_INTPIPE *inpipe`, break point is triggered.

Does anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Server will not receive data until client side pipe pushes a terminal signal.

```
//push terminal signal    
inputPipe.push(inputPipe.state, NULL, 0);
```